# How to style tags in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, html5-video, carrierwave, html5-audio

Does anyone know some quality techniques and methods for styling audio_tag, video_tag and image_tag properties in rails?, 
I'm using the carrier wave gem.

```
  <%= image_tag "http://s3.amazonaws.com/#{ENV['ABC']}#{event.attachment.thumb}" %>

  <%= audio_tag "http://s3.amazonaws.com/#{ENV['ABC']}#{event.audio}", :controls => true %>

  <%= video_tag "http://s3.amazonaws.com/#{ENV['ABC']}#{event.video}", :size => "320x240", :controls => true %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS**

This is a question of CSS - either style the element itself (with the `class` option), or wrap the element inside a `div` to give it styling that way

I know for sure you can use `class: "class` for [`image_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag):

```
<%= image_tag ..., class: "your_class" %>
```

In terms of `audio_tag` and `video_tag`, I would style them inside a `div` like this:

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: "your_class" do %>
   <%= audio_tag ... %>
<% end %>
```

--

This will allow you to style the elements within the [CSS asset pipelin](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-the-asset-pipeline-questionmark)e:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
.your_class { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks Rich, I'm not sure if this actually affects the player or the way the default is displayed, will explore a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

You can always add HTML attributes to this tags. For example:

```
audio_tag "http://s3.amazonaws.com/#{ENV['ABC']}#{event.audio}", controls: true, class: "my-sexy-player"
```

Answer (score 0):

Image tag can be styled like so:

```
<%= image_tag ... , class: "your-class" %>
```

From my experience, you cannot style the audio or video tags given each browser's is different. You can either use a JS library that's great for cross browser or create you're own (depends on the function of your player + I wouldn't recommend it!)